# C++ pointer to own struct member has different value after reassignment

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, struct

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and came across a bug which I cannot understand. I have this code as an example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
    int a = 0;
    int c;
    int *b;

    Foo(int n)
    {
        a = n;
        b = &c;
    }
};

struct Bar
{
    Foo nestedFoo = Foo(0);

    Bar(int n)
    {
        std::cout << "bar constructor nestedFoo before:" << std::endl;
        std::cout << &nestedFoo.a << std::endl;
        std::cout << nestedFoo.b << std::endl;
        nestedFoo = Foo(n);
        std::cout << "bar constructor nestedFoo after:" << std::endl;
        std::cout << &nestedFoo.a << std::endl;
        std::cout << nestedFoo.b << std::endl;
    }
};

struct App
{
    Bar bar = Bar(2);
};

int main()
{
    App app;
    Bar bar = Bar(10);
    Foo foo = Foo(5);

    std::cout << "foo before:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << &foo.a << std::endl;
    std::cout << foo.b << std::endl;

    foo = Foo(20);
    std::cout << "foo after:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << &foo.a << std::endl;
    std::cout << foo.b << std::endl;

    std::cout << "bar.nestedFoo:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << &bar.nestedFoo.a << std::endl;
    std::cout << bar.nestedFoo.b << std::endl;

    std::cout << "app.bar.nestedFoo:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << &app.bar.nestedFoo.a << std::endl;
    std::cout << app.bar.nestedFoo.b << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I expected the pointer and the address of the member to be the same after the reassignment but it seems this is not the case, `&Foo.a` and `Foo.b` have different values:

```
bar constructor nestedFoo before: 
0058FEE8                          
0058FEE8                          
bar constructor nestedFoo after:  
0058FEE8                          
0058FC24                          
bar constructor nestedFoo before: 
0058FED8                          
0058FED8                          
bar constructor nestedFoo after:  
0058FED8                          
0058FD04                          
foo before:                       
0058FEC8                          
0058FEC8                          
foo after:                        
0058FEC8                          
0058FDF8                          
bar.nestedFoo:                    
0058FED8                          
0058FD04                          
app.bar.nestedFoo:                
0058FEE8                          
0058FC24
```

At first I thought it only happened when I had Foo as a member of another struct, but it seems to happen even at a top-level assignment. So what am I doing wrong?

Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

**Edit:** showing that assigning `b` to `&c` which is a member that doesn't get (explicitly) reassigned also doesn't work.

Comment: when you assign, the target's pointer points to the source's int and becomes dangling when the source dies

Comment: @M.M are you saying it points to `n`? Then why it does also happen to members which are NOT reassigned?

Comment: The pointer points into to the temporary object you create that overwrites your original object.

Comment: First of all: Please clean up your code, it is way too complicated to get anyone to read it and help you. Secondly, @M.M and @Galik are right. You didn't define `operator=` therefore the standard one is taken. This leads to a bit-by-bit copy of your class, which is incorrect, because the pointer is just copied, but no check is made if it still points to a valid memory location. Therefore it points to an invalid location, when you temporary is deleted. (`Foo(20)`, and `Foo(n)` are temporarily constructed, their values copied, and then deleted.)

Comment: By the way... Why do you want to point to a member variable inside the same class anyway? Just use the variable and take the memory location if necessary...

Comment: You should probably take a look at ["The rule of three/five/zero"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: Not very sure but I assume the compiler is optimizing away variables b and c in one case. Check your code at cpp.sh. Also try to run at debug mode to see the output.